# |WLST| Is it possible to undo changes from activated session?

Tags: oracle, session, undo, osb, wlst

Is it possible to undo (with creating a new change or without - it really doesn't matter) changes activated in one of previous session in Oracle Service Bus 11g using WebLogic Scipting Tool (WLST)?

I can't find any example for similar case except one question on Oracle forum which is without any answer for 2 years
https://community.oracle.com/thread/3809612

All I found is createSession(), activateSession(), discardSession() and sessionExists() on SessionManagementBean but this is only for current session. There is nothing for already activated.

I would like to code in WSLT the same what does the arrows in the red circle on the right in this image (column "Options"):
[Configuration changes - how to undo changes from existing and already activated session](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XoIuW.png)

Comment: activateSession takes a string argument as session identifier - what happens when you pass an old/previous session ID as parameter?

Comment: @Jang-VijaySingh It doesn't work as all methods of SessionManagementBean work on existing, currently open sessions. It can't access anything what is already activated.

Comment: What I would like to achieve is to list activated changes, like it is on "**View Configuration Changes**" page and then undo selected configuration change, like it is possible to do via **sbconsole** from this page http://localhost:7001/sbconsole/sbconsole.portal?_nfpb=true&_pageLabel=ChangeManagement&ViewChangesPortletdummy_name=dummy_value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a matter of this mBean:

'com.bea:Name=Config.XBus Kernel,Type=com.bea.wli.config.mbeans.ConfigMBean'

and its methods:

- getExecutionHistory
- undoTask

Comment: Do you have an example of how to do it (python)? Thanks.